# How can I restore my Mac OS file system to the state it was a couple of weeks ago?

Tags: macos, file, return, filesystems, system

Recently I've downloaded a bunch of emulators and other stuff on my Mac Mini. It all turned out very useless and instead of just deleting/uninstalling the new files, I would like my computer to go to the point before they were created – mainly to make registry clean and to avoid viruses, because many of them were probably bundled from Internet.

I know about a couple of ways to do system restoration to the earlier point, such as Time Machine. I'm just not sure if it gives a desired effect.

Comment: Have you been running Time Machine? Do you have a Time Machine backup of your machine from before installing the tools? If yes then see [Recover all your files from a Time Machine backup](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/recover-all-your-files-mh15638/13.0/mac/13.0). If Time Machine has not been enabled you may want to see [Back up your files with Time Machine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-files-mh35860/13.0/mac/13.0) for the next time.

Comment: Actually, I remember about it... I saw it when I was browsing program files on Finder but then I didn't pay much attention to Time Machine, I thought it's just a game or smth like that. Thanks so much for explanation :)